# Storing different subclasses in a vector

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to store different subclasses in a vector of `unique_ptr < BaseClass >`. This approach seems to work when the subclasses are one layer deep but fails when the subclasses are two layers deep.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int foo;
 public:

    explicit A(int bar)
    {
        foo = bar;
    }

    int getFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }

    virtual void func1() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
 public:
    using A::A;
};

class C : public A
{
 public:
    virtual void func2() = 0;
    using A::A;
};

class D : public B
{
 public:

    using B::B;

    void func1()
    {
        cout << "D1" << endl;
    }
};

class E : public C
{
 public:

    using C::C;

    void func1()
    {
        cout << "E1" << endl;
    }
    void func2()
    {
        cout << "E2" << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<A> > vec;
    vec.emplace_back(new D(1));
    vec.emplace_back(new E(2));
    vec[0]->func1(); // Okay
    vec[1]->func1(); // Okay
    vec[1]->func2(); // error: 'class A' has no member named 'func2'
    E foo(3);
    foo.func2(); // Okay

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only storing pointers to class A , you can call func1 if it is overloaded .

However , func2 does't exist inside class A , so even if the pointer is pointer to a class C which has a func2 , you are handling it as a pointer to a class A , therefore you cannot invoke func2 , because func2 doest not means anything in class A's context.

Answer (score 0):

You must look at how polymorphism works : if you have a pointer on A you can only call one of its method. In your sample A::func2() has no sense

Answer (score 0):

In Polymorphism, you need to implement all methods you are going to use later in the class you are actually pointing to:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func();
    virtual void func2();
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    void func();
}
class C : public A
{
public:
    void func2()
}
```

Same goes for variables. Now if you are going to call func2 of A, literally nothing is going to happen. If you have return-types, you have to search for a more clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the way you store the pointer. The problem is simply that A has no method `func2`.

```
  A* p = new E(2);
  p->func2();
```

will fail as well.

Either you need to add func2 to A or cast p to an E pointer.